# split WrappedArray into multiple rows and columns

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm new to scala. I'm trying to split a WrappedArray, but to no success. I have a dataframe that contains one row with data that I transformed from an xml.

If I run `df.printSchema` I get:

```
root
 |-- WrappedArray: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Cols: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- col5: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _xmlns: string (nullable = true)
```

If I run `df.head()` I get:

```
 [[[[WrappedArray([1,2019-11-29T00:00:00,06:00,1 Center1,55]
 , [2,2020-03-28T00:00:00,06:00,2 Center2,57]
 , [3,2020-07-01T00:00:00,06:00,3 Center3,58])],https://centers.net/]]]
```

I would like to get a dataframe with 5 columns looking like this:

```
col1   col2                  col3    col4         col5
1      2019-11-29T00:00:00   06:00   1 Center1    55
2      2020-03-28T00:00:00   06:00   2 Center2    57
3      2020-07-01T00:00:00   06:00   3 Center3    58
```

I've seen a lot of post on StackOverflow with post similar to mine, but the cases were a little bit different, because  the wrapArrays was already split into multiple rows. I've tried (i.e. collection.mutable.WrappedArray) to adjust it to my case, but I'm new to scala and it's quite overwhelming to me.

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spark dataframe dsl to do it like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode}    

df.withColumn("exploded", explode(col("WrappedArray.Response.Result.Cols")))
  .select(
    col("exploded.col1").as("col1"),
    col("exploded.col2").as("col2"),
    col("exploded.col3").as("col3"),
    col("exploded.col4").as("col4"),
    col("exploded.col5").as("col5")
  )
```

This will explode the array that you have in your schema creating a row per element and then select each of the col fields from the array element into its own column.